# java how to cast unknown object to an array

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have following code:

```
Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

if(result instanceof Publisher) {
  return (Publisher<?>)result;
}

if(result instanceof Iterable<?>) {
  return Flux.fromIterable((Iterable<?>)result);
}

if(result.getClass().isArray()) {
  //ERROR HERE: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Object conforms to T[]
  return Flux.fromArray(result);
}
```

I want to pass the `result` as an array to `Flux.fromArray` but I don't know how to cast it to an array? Or any better solution? I want to return a Publisher

Comment: `return Flux.fromArray((Object[]) result);`? (Also, use `if (result instanceof Object[])` as the condition)

Comment: in my case, result is int[], it will throw class cast exception: ` class [I cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; ([I and [Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Comment: but the result is not only int[], it may be Integer[], Dto[], long[] etc

Comment: [`Flux.fromArray`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromArray-T:A-) doesn't have primitive array overloads, so it wouldn't work for an `int[]` anyway.

Comment: thanks, could you help to summarize to separate answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux does not work with primitive types, so if you want to use, for example `Flux.fromArray()`, then you should convert your array of primitives to array of objects.

To simplify converting there is `ArrayUtils.toObject()` method from `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils`, but it has multiple implementations depending on the primitive type: `long`, `byte`, `int` and etc.

However, in your case you have to somehow determine the actual type of values within the array. It is possible, but not really good solution, it is because you honestly have not a good design.

The method to achieve this would look like this:

```
public Object[] convert(Object array) {
    Class<?> componentType = array.getClass().getComponentType();
    if (componentType.isPrimitive()) {
        if (array instanceof boolean[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((boolean[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof int[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((int[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof long[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((long[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof short[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((short[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof double[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((double[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof char[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((char[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof byte[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((byte[]) array);

        } else if (array instanceof float[]) {
            return ArrayUtils.toObject((float[]) array);
        }
    }
    return (Object[]) array;
}
```

And your piece of code :

```
if(result.getClass().isArray()) {
    return Flux.fromArray(convert(result));
}
```

It would work the way you expected, however, as I said it looks like a bad design.

Comment: Note `array instanceof boolean[]` is easier than `array.getClass().equals(boolean[].class)` (etc).

Comment: edited my answer since instanceOf is really easier and more readable